# how to get the context of the caller activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-context

In an android app I need to make for school I have an activity that creates groups, this should be accessed from a group list activity, which needs to be given as the context. When the user makes a group he shouldn't be able to go back to the create group activity. The group list activity gives itself with the intent, but I get null pointer exceptions when I try to run the app.

the creation of the intent:

```
    public void createGroup(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewGroupActivity.class);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable(NewGroupActivity.EXTRA_CONTEXT, this);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

the line that requests the data: `this.mContext = (Context) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable(EXTRA_CONTEXT);`

the part that crashes:

```
                                // this crashes
        Intent intent = new Intent(this.mContext, GroupActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Can you please better specify what your program should do ? It seems a bit unclear to me now.

Comment: this activity makes an group object to be send to the server. after that it will go back to the groups list. it needs to know where it came from with the context, but that can not be this activity, because the group is already created, and thus no need to go back to a create group activity

Answer (score 0):

You are confused. When you create an `Intent` like this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivity.class);
```

the `context` parameter is ONLY used to get the package name of the app. That's it. So you don't need to send your `Context` in an "extra".

To launch the`GroupActivity` from `NewGroupActivity` you can just do this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GroupActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I don't want to use this, as you shouldn't be able to go back here without you pressing a button

Comment: Sorry, you are still confused. I don't understand your problem. Please explain in more detail what you want to do. What do you mean by "go back here" and what button?

Comment: you shouldn't be able to go back here by using the back button available on all android phones.

Comment: Still don't understand. You have a crash. I told you how to fix the crash. It doesn't change anything about the back button behaviour. The normal behaviour of the BACK button is to finish the current `Activity` to return to the `Activity` that is underneath it in the stack. If you don't want the normal behaviour, then you can override `onBackPressed()` and do something else. This has nothing to do with the solution to your crash. Please explain the problem again.

Comment: I need behaviour simular to finnish, that is why i need to give the context to the other activity

Comment: Still don't understand what you mean. Please explain what you want to do. It isn't clear. In any case, you cannot pass a `Context` in an `Intent`. Usually it isn't necessary. There are ways to remove other activites from the stack using `Intent` flags and other solutions. Please explain exactly what you are trying to accomplish. Draw a picture if needed.